# Get the return value of a parameter of async function

Tags: c++

I want to get return value of the function `wait_for_user_input` before `if` condition!

```cpp
int wait_for_user_input(){
    // get input user
    // return input user
}
const auto future = std::async( std::launch::async, wait_for_user_input);
while( future.wait_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(200) ) == std::future_status::timeout ){
    // do somthing
}
if ("return of wait_for_user_input"="x"){
    // do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `async`, you need to call [`future::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) on your `future`.